# Distribute an iOS 8 app with extension

Tags: ios, ios8, provisioning-profile, ios-app-extension, entitlements

I am stuck at this. Can anyone gives me a pointer or URL to a help site on this?

Like there are now 2 bundle ID (one for app, one for the extension), which should I choose when I create an app entry in iTunes Connect? Should I create a special distribution provision profile for it?

The normal distribution profile will gives me error like these when I upload:

[image]

I have read through the App Distribution web site (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH1-SW1) and cannot figure out how to add the entitlements in distribution profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create one provisioning profile for one target. The host app and its extensions are considered separate targets.

You can just tap on the target in Xcode.

You can't do entitlement to distribution profile. They are added to the app.